# How to increase upload limit in PHP.ini on Google App Engine

Tags: linux, wordpress, google-app-engine

I have successfully installed Wordpress on Google App Engine and it went very smoothly.

I logged into WPAdmin, and when I try to install my theme it says "Are you sure you want to do this? Please try again.'

I have researched this error, and found that it is because the default size that PHP allows for upload is less than the size of the theme I am uploading.

I have tried to edit the PHP.INI file, but my login does not have access to edit the file. I have searched the Google help files, and other forums and it looks like Google locks this file down.

From what I can see, there are two options. a) Copy the file from my hard drive to the correct directory on the server using FTP or an upload, or b) Edit the PHP.INI file.

Does anyone know how I can do either one of these?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The two options you mention are not mutually exclusive. You are right, you may solve your PHP size limitations [by editing locally your PHP.INI file](https://www.elegantthemes.com/blog/tips-tricks/is-the-wordpress-upload-limit-giving-you-trouble-heres-how-to-change-it), whereby ftp transfer helps you download and upload it to the App Engine. The linked article covers the situation in which your web host does not grant you direct access the PHP.INI file.